# Too few arguments error, but passing in enough arguments?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, arguments

Here is my code. I can't see any place where I am going wrong:

```
141 void TopPre (char * filename, TNode * t,char * arr,FILE * fp)
142 {
143   if (t == NULL)
144   {
145     return;
146   }
147
148
149   TopPre(char * filename,t->l,char * arr,FILE * fp);
150   if (t->val == '0')
151   {
152     TopHelp(arr[0],filename,fp);
153   }
154   else
155   {
156     arr[0] = '1';
157     TopHelp(arr[0],filename,fp);
158     arr[0] = t->val;
159     TopHelp(arr[0],filename,fp);
160   }
161
162   TopPre(char * filename,t->r,char * arr,FILE * fp );
163   if (t->val == '0')
164   {
165     TopHelp(arr[0],filename,fp);
166   }
167   else
168   {
169     arr[0] = '1';
170     TopHelp(arr[0],filename,fp);
171     arr[0] == t->val;
172     TopHelp(arr[0],filename,fp);
173   }
```

However, I am getting this error whenever I call TopPre:

```
huffman.c:149:10: error: expected expression before ‘char’
   TopPre(char * filename,t->l,char * arr,FILE * fp);
          ^
huffman.c:149:10: error: too few arguments to function ‘TopPre’
huffman.c:141:6: note: declared here
 void TopPre (char * filename, TNode * t,char * arr,FILE * fp)
      ^
huffman.c:162:10: error: expected expression before ‘char’
   TopPre(char * filename,t->r,char * arr,FILE * fp );
          ^
huffman.c:162:10: error: too few arguments to function ‘TopPre’
huffman.c:141:6: note: declared here
 void TopPre (char * filename, TNode * t,char * arr,FILE * fp)
```

I might be missing something obvious, but I seriously can't see it. Some help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: `TopPre(char * filename,t->l,char * arr,FILE * fp);` that's not how you call a function!!

Comment: apologies for the extremely wasteful question. sorry for wasting your time too.

Answer (score 3):

In your code

```
 TopPre(char * filename,t->l,char * arr,FILE * fp);
```

is not a valid syntax for a function call, you don't need the data types, only the arguments.

Change it to something like

```
TopPre(filename, t->l, arr, fp);
```

given that the arguments are appropriate.